# VSCode Extension createTextEditorDecorationType ignore whitespace

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on an extension which colors some text within the editor based on some condition. Unfortunately, it looks like the style applied to the text is also applied to the whitespace characters when the user has `editor.renderWhitespace` enabled.

I can't find anything in the [API](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api) which gives the option of ignoring the whitespace when coloring.

Does anyone know of a way to leave the color of the whitespace characters intact?

Comment: Is it a viable option: "Use another condition to check if the character is whitespace and then change its color to transparent" See [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25956#issuecomment-299350560)

Comment: Hmmm, that could be exactly what I need. You should throw that up as an answer and if it works I'll mark it :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting to change the color and opacity of whitespace characters when made visible as discussed [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25956#issuecomment-299350560). It says that you could use:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorWhitespace.foreground": "#FF0000"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The colors for the whitespace is taken from the `invisibles` property in themes, so the color is customizable via themes.

```
<key>invisibles</key>
<string>#3B3A32</string>
```

for more information please read this issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5892)